# Appium Java: How do I find an element that has no id, name, or class name when using xpath always returns NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, android, appium

I am trying to use appium to automate an app, and there are some problems. Many of the tags don't have an id. In my current situation, the element that I want to click has a parent element that has an id. However, that parent element encompasses much more than what I want to click, so just clicking that parent element probably won't work. I want to click the 1st child of that parent element, but that child has no id. Neither the 1st child nor the 1st child's child (the grandchild of the parent), nor the child of that grandchild (a.k.a the great grandchild), nor any of the 3 children of that great grandchild have ids. The grandchild and those last 3 children have resource-ids, but appium (in Java) has no driver.findElementByResourceId() method. None of these elements have a name or content-desc or accessibility ids or anything. When I tried to use driver.getElementByTagName(), I get an error that says that the tagname selector is not supported for this session. Using xpath for some reason always returns a NoSuchElementException.

Apparently the class attribute is not the same as class name, so whenever I try driver.findElements(By.className()).get(0), I always get an IndexOutOfBoundsException because the size of the returned list is apparently 0 (The elements have the class attribute, but not the class name attribute). I just don't know what to do here.

Here is some relevant info:
I am using UiAutomator2 and Android 12.

In Java, I am using appium version 7.0.0 and selenium version 3.141.59.

Does anyone know what kind of selectors I could use here?

Here is an image of what I am talking about (though I have censored the resource ids):
[image]

The highlighted element is the parent that has the id, but encompasses too much. The rest of the elements in this picture would suffice for me to click, but they have no ids, names, text, link text, content-desc, or accessibilty ids.

Answer (score 2):

You can always construct a xpath using resource-id like as below,

```
.//android.widget.textView[@resource-id = 'login']
```

and the same as above will work as expected for mobile app automation.

Also, you can search on the UI with above xpath using Appium Inspector Tool as well.